# Corona SDK Tap event, Trigger only 1 event?

Tags: sdk, lua, coronasdk, event-listener, openurl

Sorry i couldn't be very specific in the question.
I am working on an app, that links out to the internet.

I am having trouble with it, because it opens multiple tabs in the browser, from touching the button one time.

Usually 5 tabs are opened.

Here is my code...  I'm sure it is as simple as stopping the function somehow, but i am still learning corona /lua coding.

Thanks for any and all help/suggestions!

```
--Party Button
local function partyListener( event )
    system.openURL( "http://www.themcgrawgalleria.com/party" )
    return true
end

local partyImage = display.newImage( "party.png" ,0 , 225,true)
partyImage.x = display.contentCenterX
partyImage.xScale = .25
partyImage.yScale = .25
partyImage:addEventListener( "touch", partyListener )
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use:

```
partyImage:addEventListener( "tap", partyListener )
```

Instead of:

```
partyImage:addEventListener( "touch", partyListener )
```

Because `touch` events has 3 phases named: `began`,`moved` and `ended`. So if you try a button click with touch event, you may call your listener in those phases. Using `tap` can solve your issue.
For more details, visit: 
[Corona-->touch](http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/event/touch/index.html)  and [Corona-->tap](http://docs.coronalabs.com/guide/events/touchMultitouch/index.html)

Keep Coding......... :)

Comment: Remember to accept this as an aswer so others can find it too.